# Animate one object when another is focused

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I have multiple sections to a form. Each section has an indicator as to what step the user is on. I want to have it so that whenever an input within a section is focused it begins an animation on the indicator. I'm unable to use :focus-within due to it not being browser standard right now.

Right now I've saved the pulse animation as a hover effect, but I would like for this animation to start when the input is focused. I thought about using JQuery, but I wasn't able to figure it out myself.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```css
@keyframes pulse {
  0%,
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 109, 168, 0);
  }
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(0, 109, 168, 0.5);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(0, 109, 168, 0);
  }
}

#indicator {
  background-color: #006da8;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#indicator:hover {
  animation: pulse 2s ease infinite;
}

#indicator p {
  padding-top: 3px;
  margin: 5px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}


/* what i think i want to do? */

input:focus {
  /* somehow start indicator animation???
     Maybe use javascript? */
}
```

```html
<form>

  <section>
    <div id="indicator">
      <p>1</p>
    </div>

    <input type="text" />
    <input type="email" />
    <input type="password" />
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="indicator">
      <p>2</p>
    </div>

    <input type="text" />
    <input type="email" />
    <input type="password" />
  </section>

  <section>
    <div id="indicator">
      <p>3</p>
    </div>

    <input type="text" />
    <input type="email" />
    <input type="password" />
  </section>

</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert each section to a flexbox. Position the `.indicator` after the inputs, and use `order: -1` to move it to the top. Now you can use the sibling combinator `input:focus~.indicator` to call the animation.

```css
@keyframes pulse {
  0%,
  40% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px rgba(0, 109, 168, 0);
  }
  0% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(0, 109, 168, 0.5);
  }
  100% {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(0, 109, 168, 0);
  }
}

section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50vw;
}

section .indicator {
  order: -1;
}

.indicator {
  background-color: #006da8;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  line-height: 25px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
}

input:focus~.indicator {
  animation: pulse 2s ease infinite;
}
```

```html
<form>

  <section>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="email" />
    <input type="password" />

    <div class="indicator">1</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="email" />
    <input type="password" />

    <div class="indicator">2</div>
  </section>

  <section>
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="email" />
    <input type="password" />

    <div class="indicator">3</div>
  </section>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

So, when I originally wrote this question I didn't include an important detail. I did not know at the time that the library that I was using when this problem arose automatically wraps all inputs in a div. I cannot remove the library as it is vital to the project. So I found a way to also do this is jQuery and I thought I would put it on here in case anyone in the future needed it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.inputAnimator').focus(function () {
        $(this).closest('.section').find('.numeral').addClass('pulseAnimator');
    });
    $('.inputAnimator').blur(function () {
        $(this).closest('.section').find('.numeral').removeClass('pulseAnimator');
    });
});
```

```css
form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0 ;
}

.numeral {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #006da8;
  
  line-height: 25px;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}

.pulseAnimator {
  animation: pulse 2s ease infinite;
}

@keyframes pulse {
  0%,40% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 10px rgba(0, 109, 168, 0);
    }
    0% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(0, 109, 168, 0.5);
    }
    100% {
        box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(0, 109, 168, 0);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <div class="section">
    <div class="numeral">1</div>
    <input class="inputAnimator" type="text" />
    <input class="inputAnimator" type="text" />
    <input class="inputAnimator" type="password" />
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="section">
    <div class="numeral">2</div>
    <input class="inputAnimator" type="text" />
    <input class="inputAnimator" type="text" />
    <input class="inputAnimator" type="password" />
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="section">
    <div class="numeral">3</div>
    <input class="inputAnimator" type="text" />
    <input class="inputAnimator" type="text" />
    <input class="inputAnimator" type="password" />
  </div>
</form>
```